# Remap / posterize image colors using list of colors in imagemagick

Tags: image, imagemagick, rmagick, dragonfly-gem

Let's say I have this image:

[image: Oranges]

And I want to reduce the number of colors to 3, like so:

[image]

To do this, I applied the following command:

`convert orange.jpg -remap palette.png orange_output.png`

where palette.png looks like this:
[image]

**Is there a way to perform this conversion without the use of a palette image?** Ideally, I would like to provide a list of colors and have it convert the image that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to perform this conversion without the use of a palette image?

Yes, but it wouldn't be as easy as providing a color palette. At a very high level, you would pre-process the source image by applying [dither](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#dither), [dropping colors](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#colors), and maybe even adjust [tree-depth](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#treedepth). After which it would be simple operation of replacing colors.

```sh
convert source.jpg -colors 3 -treedepth 3 -dither FloydSteinberg +remap out.png
```

[image: Pre-process without colorswap]

*omitting [-draw color](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#draw) replace example*

But I imagine you really want an easy oneliner. Luckily remap accepts both text: format and pipes

```sh
convert -size 1x1 xc:green xc:orange xc:blue -append txt:- | \
        convert source.jpg -remap txt:- out.png
```

[image: Remapped colors]

The text format is vary simple, and can be dynamically created & stored with any scripting language.

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,3,65535,srgb
0,0: (0%,50.1961%,0%)  #000080800000  green
0,1: (100%,64.7059%,0%)  #FFFFA5A50000  orange
0,2: (0%,0%,100%)  #00000000FFFF  blue
```

You can probable reduce that down to...

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,3,255,rgb
0,0: #008000  green
0,1: #FFA500  orange
0,2: #0000FF  blue
```

Comment: `convert -size 1x1 xc:#ffffff -append colors.png` creates a 1x1 image with a black pixel instead of white. I am using ImageMagick 7.0.7-22

Comment: I figured this out: ImageMagick loves to do premature optimization, so it optimized the single-pixel white image to be a binary PNG. To force IM to output an sRGB png, run `convert -size 1x1 xc:#ffffff -append -define png:color-type=6 colors.png` instead.